# How to get operators from a string in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want extract all operators from string/statement. I have a list of operators.

```
operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '**', '//', '=', '+=', '-=', '==', '*=', '/=', '%=', '//=', '!=', '&=', '|=', '^=', '>>=', '<<=']
```

You can use regular expression also.

**Example-**

Input -

```
2*5**10
45/78
7//9
p //=  2
if p <= 0 and h > 0
```

Output-

```
[*, **]
[/]
[//]
[//=]
[<=, >]
```

Issue I faced -

The problem arises when i check each operator is in string or not one be one.
For input `2**5`, i get output as `[**, *]` but i want only `[**]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `operators` lists you're missing `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=`. Also sort the `operators` list by lenght before creating the regex:

```
import re

operators = ['>', '<', '<=', '>=', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '**', '//', '=', '+=', '-=', '==', '*=', '/=', '%=', '//=', '!=', '&=', '|=', '^=', '>>=', '<<=']
r = re.compile( '|'.join( '(?:{})'.format(re.escape(o)) for o in sorted(operators, reverse=True, key=len)) )

tests = [
'2*5**10',
'45/78',
'7//9',
'p //=  2',
'if p <= 0 and h > 0']

for t in tests:
    print(t, r.findall(t))
```

Prints:

```
2*5**10 ['*', '**']
45/78 ['/']
7//9 ['//']
p //=  2 ['//=']
if p <= 0 and h > 0 ['<=', '>']
```